# Error Code: 1305 FUNCTION table.encode does not exist

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm having a proble in MySQL 8.0. When i try to run this query: select encode('banana', '123'), I'm getting the error from the title.

P.S: I've already tried the following method and still doesn't work: SET SQL_MODE = IGNORE_SPACE and some other solutions found around the website

Obs.: I'm using the latest version, as from today, of MySQL Workkbench

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As mysql documentation for [v5.7 on encryption functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html) says:

> The ENCODE() and DECODE() functions are deprecated in MySQL 5.7, and should no longer be used. Expect them to be removed in a future MySQL release. Consider using AES_ENCRYPT() and AES_DECRYPT() instead.

If you check out the same documentation for v8.0, encode() function is not listed. Please, use AES_ENCRYPT() function instead.